# How to get the raw content of a selected tag using QueryPath

Tags: php, libxml2, querypath

I am using QueryPath and I want to be able to get the raw content of a given selector.

I can't find in the docs anything other than `->text()` to get contents. this gives me text so that the `My l2 <a href="/alink">alink</a>` becomes `My l2 alink`, but I want the `a` tag on my output.

How could i get the output `My l2 <a href="/alink">alink</a>` ?

I've writen some pseudo code below

```
$html = '<div class="col-sm-11 col-12 offset-sm-1 collapse">
        <ul>
            <li>
                My li1
            </li>
            <li>
                My l2 <a href="/alink">alink</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>';

    $dom = qp($html, "li"); 
    foreach($dom as $key){
       $key->text();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```html
       $key->innerHtml();
```

instead of text()